# LinkedIn connection marked unsafe

Tags: tls, web-browser

From time to time my LinkedIn connection gets marked as unsafe: no green lock next to the URL.

First, I believed this was a browser issue, but after I switched to another browser, the warning did not disappear (for now, my browsers are Opera and Chrome).

First, the connection is always safe, but once I enter the job search section and  start scrawling through job offers, every now and then, although not often, the safe connection status turns into unsafe. Does anyone have an idea of what may cause such change?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on the "non-secure" icon, it should tell you why. You're probably not using HTTPS.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I studied the "non-secure" before posting the question and clicking on the icon showed no warnings. Also, the https connection obviously remained in place.

Comment: Chrome's security tab in the developer toolbar should explain any warnings. But lack of further warnings probably means HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

maybe that's because of the content on the pages.
For example, some pages that are monitored strictly would be more secure, while pages with rather changeable content might be considered suspicious

Comment: This is not correct at all. This is a TLS/HTTPS and certificate issue.